Как сделать кнопку, которая сохраняет Tkinter в файл?
Есть кнопка "Сохранить". К ней нужно привязать функцию сохранения Tkinter в файле всех данных программы. Напишите, пожалуйста, функцию для кнопки, по нажатию которой сохраняется файл с расширением .py (либо с другим, если это возможно), и при открытии сохраненного файла открывается программа Tkinter со всеми введенными данными пользователем.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

def add_catalog():
    new_catalog = catalog_entry.get()
    catalogs_listbox.insert(0, new_catalog)
    catalog_entry.delete(0, tk.END)


win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Сохранятель')
win.geometry('390x310')
win.resizable(False, False)

catalog_entry = tk.Entry(width=21)
catalog_entry.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalog_entry.place(x=51, y=30)
tk.Button(text="Добавить", width=9, command=add_catalog).place(y=30, x=268)

catalogs_listbox = tk.Listbox(width=29, height=9)
catalogs_listbox.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalogs_listbox.place(x=49, y=60)

save_program = tk.Button(master=win, text='Сохранить')
save_program.place(x=200, y=278)

win.mainloop()


Используйте базу данных, sqlite3 как пример. И при запуске программы читайте оттуда данные, а при  сохранении обновляйте данные.

Не нужно сохранять данные в файлы с кодом. Используйте базу данных, либо какие-то форматы предназначенные конкретно для хранения данных - как json, csv и т.д.
